# Could not add card - Agent refused operation

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to add the certs on my CAC card using the ssh-add commands with no luck.

```
ssh-add -s /usr/local/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so
Enter passphrase for PKCS#11: 
Could not add card "/usr/local/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so": agent refused operation
```

I even tried whitelisting the key:

```
1) ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*opensc* ----> Found the symlink

2) rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopensc.so.3

3) cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/onepin-opensc-pkcs11.so /usr/local/lib

4) cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so /usr/local/lib/

pkill ssh-agent
ssh-agent -P /usr/local/lib/`
```

But no dice, can you please help?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

For some days I had headache with this. And for me the answer is to `sudo apt install yubico-piv-tool`

Reference: [Yubikey-SSH, Accessing the key](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Yubikey-SSH#Accessing_the_key).